# Using reflection to set property values where types are unknown

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to set value object properties at runtime. If everything were a string, I may not be asking this question, but that's not the case. I have a web service that returns json and I want to use the json returned by the service to populate the object. I have an ArrayList of strings called alphabeticalKeys that contains sorted keys in the json string. Here is the code I am using to dynamically populate the object (user):

```
for(String fieldName : alphabeticalKeys){
    Log.d("JSON:" + fieldName, json.getString(fieldName));
    Field f = userClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(user, jsonObject.get(fieldName));
}
```

In the json data set, there are strings, doubles and more. This is part of a factory class where the type of object being returned is unknown at compile time. Also, the json fields'  data types may vary depending on the type of object needed.

The json output matches the field names in the returned object, so I am looking for a way to handle the different data types returned in the json output. Can somebody offer up a suggestion?

Thx! Vivian

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries available to aid in setting property values using reflection, converting to the appropriate type if necessary. For example, Spring Framework's [BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html) and  [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

There are also json libraries that will handle mapping json to/from java objects. For example, [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome). This may make it easier, especially if the json structure closely matches the java object structure.